# Network music player with smart cache

Tags: music

Usually I listen to music from a network stream with **Winamp** and **VLC**. Both these have a problem, they cache specified length of music, play it, then cache again. If your network connection was not fast enough this type of caching makes your listening experience horrible, laggy.
Is there any app that cache the stream while playing the cached stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have found nothing that proves or disproves your assumption that VLC and Winamp don't buffer while playing. But I'm very curious about this behavior. Normally every application buffers while playing.*

I did some tests with [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) and it always buffers while playing.
Here you see a radio stream together with my [network meter](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/).

I disabled all other applications, started the radio and observed it for quite a while and it was constantly downloading data (=buffering) while it was playing.

[image]

---

But my guess is that your Internet connection is to slow **or** your chosen radio stream is too slow.
You can try to expand the network buffer size of VLC, Winamp or Foobar.

1. Here is a very detailed guide on how to [increase the buffer size in Winamp](http://www.in2streams.com/helpspot/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=16)
2. In VLC you have to look for these settings. They were entered in milliseconds

   [image]
3. If you don't want to enter a specific time, you can use Foobar. It buffers up to 16385 KB which is pretty huge.

   [image]